# Selenium webdriver Unable to locate element

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, automation

I've been trying to get the element of this status message after adding an existing record. Still don't have luck on trying to make it work. Any ideas on getting this element? Any answers will be much appreciated thank you!

[image]

UPDATE::

I can get the element of [ 10:45:02 - HR206 ]Job Record Already Exists what i only need is the  Job Record Already Exists w/o the time.

Comment: What did you try, and what kind of issues did you encounter with the approach you chose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with xpath = `//ul[@id='currentMessage']/li`

```
String message=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='currentMessage']/li")).getText();
```

Thank You

Comment: i think this element is inside frame. please look into HTML and observe that if elements in iframe tag. and also try with giving wait or sleep.

Comment: if it is inside frame, please use switch to frame command, i hope you know this

Comment: Yes i already switch to the multiple frames. I'm quiet familiar with switching frames because our project have a lot of frames :(

Comment: Got the right element! just switching to the wrong frame :). Another issue is that issue seems to be getting the time. like this. [ 10:49:23 - HR206 ]Job Record Already Exists... All i need to get is the text of >>> Job Record Already Exists, is there a way to get only the Text of the element? and does not include the time.